# WP7 - How to bind the Bitmap from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I have bit map in View Model. Now I want to bind to the XAML from View Model.

```
 public static String _imgQRCode;
        public String imgQRCode
        {
            get { return _imgQRCode; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.imgQRCode, value); }
        }
```

Bit Map:-

```
imgQRCode = GenerateQRCode(phoneNumber).ToString();
```

GenerateORCode:-

```
private static WriteableBitmap GenerateQRCode(string phoneNumber)
        {
            BarcodeWriter _writer = new BarcodeWriter();

            _writer.Renderer = new ZXing.Rendering.WriteableBitmapRenderer()
            {
                Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255),
            };

            _writer.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;

            _writer.Options.Height = 400;
            _writer.Options.Width = 400;
            _writer.Options.Margin = 1;

            var barcodeImage = _writer.Write("tel:" + phoneNumber);
            return barcodeImage;
        }
```

Here i can not bind the image. Please let me any idea to bind the image from viewModel.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not bind the image to string.
So long as datacontext is correct for your  tag, you should define a property for the bitmap, e.g.

```
WriteableBitmap QRCode { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged the way you do it
```

Then have QRCode set in your other property setter, like so:

```
public String imgQRCode
        {
            get { return _imgQRCode; }
            set 
            { 
              this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.imgQRCode, value); 
              this.QRCode = GenerateQRCode(value);
            }
        }
```

then in XAML you can do `<Image Source="{Binding Path=QRCode}" />`

Comment: Hi @zaitsman.. Thanks for the reply.. It's Working. I changed the data type. And it's working..!!

Answer (score 1):

Change the data type from `string` to `WriteableBitmap` for `imgQRCode`.

Comment: Hi @New Developer.. Thanks for the reply.. I changed the data type. And it's working..!! Now it's working. Thanks..